# Unexpected Symbol 'NONE' Archive Engine - MariaDB DBForge

Tags: mysql, mariadb, archive, dbforge

I am trying to create an archive table in MariaDB using dbForge and I'm getting the following error when I save the table.

> Unexpected Symbol 'NONE'

dbForge automatically changes the following line from:

> PRIMARY KEY (ArchiveSupplierID)

To

> PRIMARY KEY USING NONE (ArchiveSupplierID)

Below is my table definition

```
CREATE TABLE supplierarchives (
    ArchiveSupplierID INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY USING NONE (ArchiveSupplierID)
)
ENGINE = ARCHIVE
AUTO_INCREMENT = 31888
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 148
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Thanks,

Comment: It does not look like the current version of dbForge (v7.2) does it, maybe it was a dbForge bug that was fixed. Still, what exactly is the statement that you run before dbForge converts it into a wrong syntax? What you've quoted as "my table definition" already has 'USING NONE'.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is fixed in the latest software version. Please upgrade your dbForge Studio for MySQL and get all the bug fixes and enhancements.
To download the product, please follow the link https://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/download.html